# Multiple Spring MVC validator for the same Controller

Tags: java, spring, validation, spring-mvc

I am having a Spring controller with a Validator defined as:

```
    @InitBinder
    protected void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
        binder.setValidator(new MyValidator(myService));
    }
```

And calling it:

```
public ResponseEntity<?> executeSomething(
   @ApiParam(name = "monitorRequest", required = true, value = "") @Valid @RequestBody MonitorRequest monitorRequest,
   HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws RESTException
```

I need to add one more `Validator` for this controller that could be called from some specific methods of this controller. Is there any way to achieve this?

**EDIT**: I am handling the Error by:

```
@ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentNotValidException.class)
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<?> processValidationError(MethodArgumentNotValidException ex) {
        BindingResult result = ex.getBindingResult();
        List<FieldError> fieldErrors = result.getFieldErrors();
        ValidationErrorObj obj =  processFieldErrors(fieldErrors);
        ResponseEntity r = new ResponseEntity(obj, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        return r;
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have more than one `InitBinder` method in a controller. It is controlled by the optional value parameter . For the javadoc of `InitBinder` : *String[]  value : The names of command/form attributes and/or request parameters that this init-binder method is supposed to apply to ... Specifying model attribute names or request parameter names here restricts the init-binder method to those specific attributes/parameters, with different init-binder methods typically applying to different groups of attributes or parameters*.

Another way would be to explicely call a complementary Validator in specific methods.

BTW : I can't see any `Errors` or `BindingResult` in your controller method signature : where do you find whether errors occured ?

Comment: @SergeBallesta Added the code which is been used for `BindingResult`. Will try using using solution and update here whether it worked or not.

Answer (score 4):

For those who are still trying to figure out how to solve this in 2017. I was facing similar issues while trying to implement 2 validators in my RestController. I followed the approach mentioned above by @Serge Ballasta.

I ended up making 2 Model each of linked to their specific Validators. The Controller methods look something like

```
@RequestMapping(value = "register", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<User> register(@Valid @RequestBody UserRegisterRequest userRegisterRequest) {
    return null;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "test", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<?> test(@Valid @RequestBody TestRequest testRequest) {
    return null;
}
```

and I created 2 initBinders to wire these validators in the controller like

```
@InitBinder("testRequest")
public void setupBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.addValidators(testValidator);
}

@InitBinder("userRegisterRequest")
public void setupBinder1(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.addValidators(userRegistrationRequestValidator);
}
```

Please note that the @RequestBody attributes (userRegisterRequest , testRequest) had to be provided as values in the @InitBinder() annotations.

By the way the in my code I handle the bindingResult in a custom ExceptionHandler class which extends `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler` which gives me freedom to do custom handling of the response.